# Set a variable in input

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to use puppeteer to login faster and i made this script, but it recognize the variable of the input as a variable of the site

```
let data = {
    email : 'mail',
    password : 'passwd'
}

async function login(data) {
  page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('#loginlb > div.c-loginlb__popup > div > form > div:nth-child(1) > input').value = data.email;
  });
}
```

The error is this: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

How can i fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass arguments after evaluate arrow function. like this `page.evaluate(pageFunction, ...pageFunction arguments)` . [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.3.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args).

```
let data = {
    email : 'mail',
    password : 'passwd'
}

async function login(_data) {
  page.evaluate((data) => {
    document.querySelector('#loginlb > div.c-loginlb__popup > div > form > div:nth-child(1) > input').value = data.email;
  },_data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `data` is not within the scope in `page.evaluate`, you can set it in `global` and retrieve it with `global` since it'll always be in scope.

```js
global['data'] = {
    email : 'mail',
    password : 'passwd'
}

async function login(data) {
  page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('#loginlb > div.c-loginlb__popup > div > form > div:nth-child(1) > input').value = global['data'].email;
  });
}
```

Comment: it looks like if the the data obj isn't in the page evaluate function

Comment: @mattmi1303 where are you calling the login function? `data` may not be in the scope

Comment: im calling the function in this way login(data);
If i log data before the page.evaluate it returns the object but not inisde

Comment: @mattmi1303 I edited my answer with a different solution.

Comment: This is the professional way `page.evaluate(pageFunction[, ...args])` https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.3.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args